# Data Passing Between Two Form with SQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to text passing another form using reader.
This code is from Form1.

```
if (count == 1) // IF Ok.
            {
                userLabel.Text = myReader[0].ToString(); // SHOW THE USERNAME
                loginSuccessTimer1.Enabled = true; // FOR TIMER
                LoginFormSuccessBG loginSuccess = new LoginFormSuccessBG();
                loginSuccess.Show(); //LoginSuccess SHOW FORM
            }
```

This code from Form2. I want to show text in this form from Form1.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userLabel2.Text = loginForm.userLabel.Text;
    }
```

But if i click the button2 on Form2; i'm taking this error on Visual Studio:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Launcher.exe Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I've set the userLabel to public and tried this on Form2.

```
userLabel2.Text = loginForm.userLabel.ToString();
```

But it's not working. Always giving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I just did it in a test app.

```
userLabel2.Text =
    (Application.OpenForms["yourForm1"] as yourForm1).userLabel.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the Form1 as a parameter to Form2's constructor. Then, if you did userLabel public, so you can access it from Form2. Here is an example:

Form1 code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
    frm.Show();
}
```

Form2 code:

```
Form1 form1;
public Form2(Form1 sender)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form1 = sender;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = form1.label1.Text;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, the LoginForm = sender; part is problem. Visual studio isn't accept it, variable olarak algılıyor :P

Comment: You should change the variable name. Probably you defined like this: "LoginForm LoginForm;" If you change the second word's first char to lowercase, it should work. (Not: değişken ismiyle tip ismi aynı olmasın.)